# ksh: Replacing a word with asterisks causes bad substitution error

Tags: ksh

I'm trying replace a specific word read from a file with asterisks of the same length.
Eg;
cat -> ***
snake -> *****

So, in my script below, it works in bash but not in ksh

```
for next in `cat $filename`; do
        rep=${next//[^\"]/*}
        echo "$next replace with $rep"
done;
```

Running it in ksh gives me a bad substitution error, Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In older versions of ksh, you'll have to use the sed command:

```
for next in `cat $filename`; do
        rep=$(print $next | sed 's/[^\"]/*/g')
        echo "$next replace with $rep"
done;
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tried this out and works like a charm

Comment: Great, can you then upvote this answer as your accepted solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tr`:

```
rep=$(printf "%s" "$next" | tr -c '"' '*')
```

Comment: I tried this as well but it seems to just return the same characters that it reads:  (ie: cat -> cat )

Comment: I get `***` when I use ` next="cat"; printf "%s" "$next" | tr -c '"' '*'`.